# Re-size/Re-scale a pdf leaving a white margin in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, resize, imagemagick

I have a pdf file that fits a A4 page format but I would like to re-size/re-scale every page so to leave a white margin on then using PHP. I've been using ImageMagick to work with pdf files but I can't find any solution for this. Does anyone know how to achieve this goal? Even if not with ImageMagick

Thank you guys!

Comment: Uh... odd question, PDF is a vector based format, so resize/rescale doesn't actually change the document, it's done in the view. What do you mean by "white margin"? Some space on all sides?

Comment: Post the command or script that you have been using to put the PDF onto A4.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz By white margin I mean some white space on all sides

Comment: @fmw42 I haven't started programming it yet because I wanted opinions before on best ways to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick command line, you can resize the image and center it onto an A4 size white background image. Or you can read the PDF with a slightly different density to make it smaller and then center it onto an A4 size white background image. Try

`convert image.pdf -resize 90% -gravity center -background white -extent 595x842 result.png`